# Implement Custom Gridview in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

Hi i am new to android development. I have made an app where picture are now shown in a gridview. But i want to make it more user friendly. I have found an example but i need some help to implement my code as the example. I want to write my UserList.java as ImageAdapter.java. I want to use imageview instead of holder. How can i do that??

Example i am trying to follow:

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.step2rock.www.photographynowroadtopro;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Sushimz on 5/7/2016.
 */
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
            R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
            R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
//            R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8,
//            R.drawable.pic_9, R.drawable.pic_10,
//            R.drawable.pic_11, R.drawable.pic_12,
//            R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14,
//            R.drawable.pic_15
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Now Here is my code.

UserList.java

```
package com.step2rock.www.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.step2rock.www.crudproject.R;
import com.step2rock.www.crudproject.UserlistActivity;
import com.step2rock.www.model.User;


public class UserList extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    UserlistActivity activity;
    ArrayList<User> users;

    public UserList(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
        mContext = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        public ImageView ivUserImage;
        public TextView tvUserName;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        activity = new UserlistActivity();
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userrow_activity, null);
            holder.ivUserImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
            holder.tvUserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        User user = new User();
        user = users.get(position);
        holder.ivUserImage.setImageBitmap(convertToBitmap(user.get_user_pic()));
        holder.tvUserName.setText(user.get_first_name());

        return convertView;
    }

    public Bitmap convertToBitmap(String base64String) {
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64String, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmapResult = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        return bitmapResult;
    }

}
```

Comment: little confuse u are posted two adapter

Comment: please minimize your code, and post only relevant code, where you getting stuck, please lose interest if its hard to understand your problem in few minutes.

Comment: Reduced my code as you mentioned :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? All you've told us is you have a GridView.

Comment: you should use [recycler view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are new to android and want to create a grid of showing pictures.

You can develop the grid like below  [**Follow this tutorial.**](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)

[image]

Comment: thanx i was looking for this...i found the partial code but its complete in here :)